# Determine all real values of $p$ for which the following series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine all real values of  $p$ for which the following series converges:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\sin(n)|^p$.

*The solution to this question said*:

It is not difficult to show that any real number $x$, there exists an integer $n > x$ such that $|\sin(n)| > \dfrac{1}{2}$. Thus whatever $p$ is, $\lim_{n \to \infty} |\sin(n)|^p \neq 0$. Therefore $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\sin(n)|^p$ is divergent for all $p$.

*My questions*: Why did they pick $\dfrac{1}{2}$ and how does the fact that there exists an integer $n > x$ such that $|\sin(n)| > \dfrac{1}{2}$  show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |\sin(n)|^p \neq 0$?

Comment: 1. Why not.
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of $1/2$ is arbitrary. Any positive number less than $1$ will work. The point is that there are sequence terms that are well separated from $0$ no matter how far you run.

---

This is the definition of a limit: If $|\sin(n)|^p \to 0$, then $|\sin n|^p < (1/2)^p$ eventually; that is, there is an $N$ such that
$$n > N \implies |\sin n|^p < \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^p$$
However, this implies that $|\sin n| < 1/2$ for all $n > N$, which you already know is *false*. Hence, the limit cannot exist.

Comment: We should check the cases of $p$ being nonpositive and positive, correct?